# getView using custom listview getting null exception

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

```
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at net.website.custom_listview.Lazy_Adapter_Custom_Listview$1.onClick(Lazy_Adapter_Custom_Listview.java:75)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-19 23:38:21.952: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am not sure what is wrong in this below code but i am getting null exception(artist)

ps: textview does exists in the layout file.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_custom_listview, null);


        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name 
        TextView link = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLink);


        // Setting all values in listview 
        artist.setText(song.get(Main_Activity_Custom_Listview.KEY_TITLE_ENGLISH));

        link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


        TextView tx =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtLink); //null exception???
        TextView artist = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.artist); // null exception???

        Log.v("link>>", "onItemClick at position" + artist.getText());

        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(PlayListActivity.this, tx.getText(), duration);
        //toast.show(); 
        }
    }); 
        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: which line are you getting NullPointerException? can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: updated my question, i have comment on the line i am getting null exception

Comment: We need more code. Specifically, the constructor for your adapter, and what you are passing to it. It almost looks like you are passing the wrong layouts and those IDs simply don't exist in what you are passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had mentioned something similar in another post. I had mentioned that you shouldn't be doing this. You need to read up on the onClick() functionality.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_custom_listview, null);

    //Make them final so that you can access them in your onClick()
    final TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name 
    final TextView tx =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLink); 
    TextView link = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLink);



    // Setting all values in listview 
    artist.setText(song.get(Main_Activity_Custom_Listview.KEY_TITLE_ENGLISH));

    link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Log.v("link>>", "onItemClick at position" + artist.getText());

        }
    }); 
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: the only difference between my code and yours is that, you have keyword final, is that right?

Comment: I had mentioned in ure last post that the onClick returns the view of the item that you have clicked on. So in this case, v.findviewbyid() doesnt mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    .
    .
    .

    vi.findViewById(R.id.dots).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

            MessagesActivity.list.getChildAt(((int) MessagesActivity.list.getItemIdAtPosition(position))-MessagesActivity.list.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.top_header).setBackgroundResource(R.layout.list_selector);

       }

    .
    .
    .
    }
```

maybe this can help you

works for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `link.setOnClickListener(....`, you are setting a `OnClickListener` for the TextView `link`, so that TextView will be the View parameter passed to your `onClick` callback, and you certainly can't get(findViewById) your *artist* view from it.

I think you intended to do `vi.setOnClickListener()`. Even that, I don't think what you intended to do is *appropriate*, since there's an `onItemClick` callback you can override for your ListView, you don't need to set OnClickListener for each of your listview items like what you are doing in the code snippet.

**EDIT:**

Take a look at [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

And then you will be doing something like this:

```
OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // handle click events for you list view here.
        // for the parameters, see the link above. 
    }
};
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
```

Comment: can you show few lines of code how to implement what you have talked about?